# TypeError: Invalid constructor input for RecognitionAudio (Google Speech-To_Text_API)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, base64, google-speech-to-text-api

I'm trying to use google's [speech-to-text api](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/), but I am stuck at this part where I need to pass audio content in the **speech.RecognitionAudio()**

```
audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)
```

with base64 of audio which I will receive through my API response, but here I'm trying to mimic this API behavior by reading and converting an audio file(.m4a) to wav (which is already base64 by default).

```
with io.open(stream_file, "rb") as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()

audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(content)
```

resulting in `TypeError: Invalid constructor input for RecognitionAudio:b'AAAAGGZ0eXBtcDQyAAAAAG1wNDFpc29tAAAAKHV1aWRcpwj7Mo5CBahhZQ7KCpWWAAAADDEwLjAuM...`

As the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionAudio) says
[image]
I am doing the same thing but still failing, maybe I'm not understanding it properly.

Please help here.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I have to pass the content defining what I'm passing

```
audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(content=audio64)
```

wasted my 3-4 hours on just this figuring out, hopefully, someone will find this helpful.